# "Layout cycle detected.Layout could not be complete." error in .net maui communitytoolkit popup

Tags: c#, xml, maui

I'm creating a setting page of my application using pop-up in .net maui.

When pasting text that exceeds the width of Entry, an error occurs that forces termination.

**XML code in the pop-up:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="PopupTest.NewPopup">
    <Border Stroke="transparent" Margin="10">
        <Grid x:Name="settingPopup" ColumnDefinitions="*" RowDefinitions="*" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Border x:Name="settingItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto" RowSpacing="10">
                    <ImageButton
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Source="closewhite.png"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Padding="{OnPlatform WinUI=8, Android=0}"
                        HeightRequest="20"
                        WidthRequest="20"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="Setting"
                        Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Border Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="*, *, *" RowSpacing="5">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Stroke="yellow">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.4*, *">
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                                        Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                                        Text="settingvalue1"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                        FontSize="Micro"/>
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout 
                                        Grid.Column="1"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Spacing="5">
                                        <Slider 
                                            x:Name="slider"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            WidthRequest="150" 
                                            Margin="10"
                                            Maximum="10" 
                                            Minimum="1"
                                            MaximumTrackColor="#424242"
                                            MinimumTrackColor="#FFFFFF"
                                            ThumbColor="#00FFA8"/>
                                        <Entry x:Name="speedEntry"
                                            Margin="0"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            WidthRequest="100"/>
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Stroke="yellow">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.4*, *">
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                                        Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                                        Text="settingvalue2"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                        FontSize="Micro"/>
                                    <Entry
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        FontSize="Small"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        MinimumWidthRequest="300"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Stroke="yellow">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.4*, *">
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                                    Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                                    Text="settingvalue3"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                    FontSize="Micro"/>
                                    <Switch 
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        ThumbColor="White"
                                        OnColor="#00FFA8"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                        VerticalOptions="End" 
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Spacing="5">

                        <Button
                            x:Name="ResetButton"
                            Text="Reset"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="SaveButton"
                            Text="Save"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

**Error message:**

> "Layout cycle detected.Layout could not be complete."

If I delete the HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" of the entry or reduce the text of the label on the left, the error will not occur.

But I don't know why the error occurs.

Comment: Based on your code, I did a test on my side(I tested on Android and windows platforms), but I couldn't reproduce this problem. How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I did the test again with the sample project that I implemented when I registered the question, but I haven't changed anything, but the error is not reproduced.
The only reproduction step is to pop up the pop-up window through the button command in the MainViewModel and paste text with a length beyond the width of the entry, but I don't think I can reproduce it anymore.
I think it was a temporary error due to a version problem or external cause.
Thank you.